# Sudo - DNS Lookup ( tcpdump )

Tags: ubuntu, networking, sudo, dns, tcpdump

I noticed that when I type `sudo SomeCommand` it hangs for a little. I started trying to figure out what was going on found one very strange thing:
when I type `tcpdump -i wlan0` and then do `sudo`, I get this:

```
IP Jebediah-PC.35662 > gateway.domain: 58284+ A? Jebediah-PC.
IP Jebediah-PC.35662 > gateway.domain: 62298+ AAAA? Jebediah-PC.
IP Jebediah-PC.45253 > gateway.domain: 22831+ PTR? 1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 
IP gateway.domain > Jebediah-PC.35662: 58284 NXDomain 0/1/0
IP gateway.domain > Jebediah-PC.35662: 62298 NXDomain 0/1/0 
IP gateway.domain > Jebediah-PC.45253: 22831 NXDomain 0/1/0
IP Jebediah-PC.44842 > gateway.domain: 33078+ PTR? 103.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
```

It looks like some sort of DNS lookup. Here is a wireshark screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: just to make it clear , "Jebediah-PC" and "galaxy-s2" are the same machine

Comment: In this instance, what is the `someCommand`?

Comment: `sudo` by itself should return a usage error. What did you _actually_ enter that triggered this DNS lookup?

Comment: One can trigger this problem with a mere `sudo true`, roaima.  I've experienced `sudo`'s sensitivity to unavailable or slow proxy DNS service, myself.

Answer (score 5):

Because sudo rules can specify a hostname, sudo has to resolve the hostnames of the local interfaces (so that it can tell if you're matching a host-specific rule). As the other [Jeff S. said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336130/117549), this is likely because /etc/hosts doesn't contain "Jebediah-PC", and so you have to wait for the DNS lookups to fail.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is too low to leave a comment so this is more of a comment than an answer.

Since you state Jebediah-PC and galaxy-s2 are the same machine, it looks like it may have to do with changes to your hostname - see the below posts.

https://serverfault.com/a/41820

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/fedora-11-sudo-has-a-20-second-start-delay-732291/#post3575840